# Interacting w/ Yahoo Placemaker in Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, yahoo-api, net-http

I'm trying to use `net/http` to interact w/ the Yahoo Placemaker API but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
host = 'wherein.yahooapis.com'
payload = {
    'documentContent' => 'Columbus Ohio',
    'appid' => APP_ID,
    'outputType' => 'json',
    'documentType' => 'text/plain'
}.to_json

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/v1/document', initheader = { 'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
req.body = payload
response = Net::HTTP.new(host).start {|http| http.request(req) }
puts "Response #{response.code} #{response.message}: #{response.body}"
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    from /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/lib/yahoo/placemaker.rb:21:in `extract'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

After fixing the @host typo I now get:

```
Response 400 Bad Request:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" xmlns:cle="http://wherein.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xml:lang="en"><yahoo:description><![CDATA[Please provide a document URL or content.]]></yahoo:description>
<yahoo:detail><code>-9999</code>
<cause>input</cause>
</yahoo:detail></yahoo:error>
```

Comment: PlaceMaker became PlaceSpotter in 2012. The Yahoo! BOSS APIs (including PlaceSpotter) are shutting down on March 31, 2016. If you're looking for a replacement or alternative, you should check out the open source project CLAVIN or the recently-launched Geoparser.io API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending them json and they seem to be looking for a regular query string in the post body. Also you should probably use httparty to consume web services unless you have a good reason not to:

```
require 'httparty'

class Yahoo
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'http://wherein.yahooapis.com/'
end

json = Yahoo.post '/v1/document', :body => {:documentContent => 'Columbus Ohio', :appid => APP_ID, :outputType => 'json', :documentType => 'text/plain'}
```

Comment: Although this solution would work, I would really like to stick w/ `net/http` as it is part of the std library and using `httparty` would add yet another gem to my already bloated application. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: Well the solution was to use standard query string format (foo=1&bar=2) in the post body. The httparty code was just a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly just a typo? `@host` should be `host` right?

Comment: I've fixed the typo but I'm now getting a different error. I've updated my question w/ the output